# POP3 buffer gets translated in a strange way. Characters are bad when they shouldn't be

Tags: python-3.x, buffer-overflow

I've been trying to write a script for a buffer overflow attack on SLmail service (Within a legal setting, in a VPN. I am following a penetration testing course.).

The issue I'm having came up while trying to define which characters were bad. As it turns out, anything above 7F is getting mangled. I have followed the exact example that my textbook gave me, I tried googling for similar examples, not a single one I found ever mentioned that issue.

In theory, the only bad characters for this particular buffer should be x00, x0a and x0d.
Here everything above 7F is a mess. I get C2s and C3s appearing every other byte, while the rest of the bytes are somehow translated. (FF turns into BF, for example.). This is rendering me completely unable to have my shellcode sent through. I've tried removing some or changing the order. No matter the order I put them in, anything above 7F will come out translated with C2/C3s every other byte.

[image]

Link to both my script code and the memory dump resulting from it.
(The for is weird, I know.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I was using py3, which required strings to be encoded.
By translating the script into py2.7, I no longer needed to encode them and they went through without any mangling.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW8QK.jpg

[image]